# How can I create curried anonymous function in scala?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, currying

How can I create an anonymous and curried function in Scala? The following two failed:

```
scala> (x:Int)(y:Int) => x*y
<console>:1: error: not a legal formal parameter
       (x:Int)(y:Int) => x*y
              ^

scala> ((x:Int)(y:Int)) => x*y
<console>:1: error: not a legal formal parameter
       ((x:Int)(y:Int)) => x*y
               ^
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To create a curried function write it as if it were multiple functions (that's actually the case ;-) ).

```
scala> (x: Int) => (y: Int) => x*y
res2: Int => Int => Int = <function1>
```

This means you have a function from Int to a function from Int to Int.

```
scala> res2(3)
res3: Int => Int = <function1>
```

alternatively you can write it like this:

```
scala> val f: Int => Int => Int = x => y => x*y
f: Int => Int => Int = <function1>
```

Comment: The last expression is a named function, how can we write the same as an anonymous function?

Comment: In the last expression, how is the symbol "=>" working? x => y => x*y

Comment: You got to have something you want to pass the function to. if you have a method/function like `def foo(f: Int => Int => Int)` you can call it like `foo( x => y => x*y)`.

Comment: @NiketKumar anonymous function: `{x => y => x * y}: (Int => Int => Int)`

Comment: @NiketKumar The last is not a named function. Or, rather, it's a named function of arity 0 which returns a curried anonymous function.